# Where is attribute table in ArcGIS Desktop when not visible?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, attribute-table

I've just updated to ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop and when I go to open an attribute table, I can not see it anywhere.

I'm wondering if it is off my screen somewhere or if its just super tiny that I can't see it.

I'm using dual monitors and it's not popping up on either.

Is there a way I can find my attribute table?

Comment: SP1 is installed. Vector data. Not sure what to try.

Comment: [This ArcGIS forum thread](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/54394-Missing-Attribute-Table) might help. Do you have a screenshot you can share? It might be on the edges and barely visible.

Comment: I tried a few ideas in there and cant pin down which one worked but it got me trying a few things. I tried right click on task bar and chose, "Show windows stacked." This maximized all windows I had open on both monitors. It stacked the ArcMap windows. In the very top left corner of the  monitor, by the ArcMap icon & document title, I could see a very small corner of the attribute table. I was able to click & drag the corner resize it, to make it larger. I was then able to click and drag the attribute table into the main screen. Thanks for giving me something to encourage the troubleshooting!

Comment: Before I tried stacking the windows, I was looking everywhere for something I could see along the edges of the monitor and I was not able to see the tiny corner. It was only when I used "Show windows stacked" that I could see the attribute table at the edge of the monitor.

Comment: We just had the same problem here and the solution posted by Sue Deforest on Dec 13'12 at 19:09 worked for us:)

Comment: ESRI eventually closes and migrates its user forums, so this link is going to go bad at some point. That is why it is so important to summarize the information in the link.

Comment: The idea given by Sue Deforest **"Show windows stacked."** then look at **"very top left corner of the monitor"**. You will see very small corner of the **attribute table**. Then **click and drag**. Finally you will get the table. This idea worked for me as well.

Comment: This answer is still relevant, and Sue's first comment below is worth reviewing. I couldn't find the attribute table when using a Remote Desktop Connection. I restarted ArcMAP and sure enough on the left hand side of the screen was a barely visible sliver of the attribute table. I could drag the window edge into my main screen and then work with it.

Answer (score 3):

go to: C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.2\ArcMap\Templates
note: change the username to your username
Delete or rename the file called "Normal.mxt". This worked for me! I found this on another forum, which I can't find a link to right now, but credit goes to that person.

Comment: As mentioned on another gis.se thread, deleting the .mxt will nix your custom toolbars. I opened the .mxt, moved things where I wanted them, and closed w/out saving and that reset the positions of windows on blank map documents moving forward.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your screen resolution is as high as possible.
I am using two screens at work, my laptop and a larger screen, but working at home on only my laptop.  I had to expand the screen to see the table in right corner.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with 2 screens make sure you you have set the size of icons on the windows desktop the same. (Accessible via Desktop => Right click => Display properties). For example set both to 100%.

Answer (score 0):

C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.2\ArcMap\Templates this worked for me too -- used Jyler's suggestion: opened mxd map, arranged it -- attribute table was barely visible lower right, closed without saving, then opened original project. voila -- attribute table right there.