# ArcMap attribute table has disappeared

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, attribute-table

I am having the same problem discussed at [Where is the attribute table in ArcGIS for Desktop when not visible?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43920).

I don't know what I did but my attribute table is now lurking somewhere but I can't find it. I use only one monitor. The previous question was resolved by right clicking on the taskbar and selecting "show windows stacked." However, I have tried right-clicking everywhere and I haven't seen an option for "show windows stacked."

I've tried quitting ArcMap but nothing changed. I do not want to have to reinstall ArcGIS Desktop nor do I want to have to change the registry.

Comment: What version of ArcGIS? (What Operating System, Windows?

Answer (score 2):

If you are comfortable deleting the template (normal.mxt), ArcMap will start with all windows in default location. Normal.mxt is just a basic template, it won't harm your existing map documents. Here is the path for normal.mxt in windows 7: C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.1\ArcMap\Templates
For other windows os, you may have to navigate to your user profile and similar drill down. Also, AppData, is a hidden folder by default. You may have to change the settings from folder options to show hidden files, folders and drives.

Answer (score 1):

the solution suggests right clicking on the task bar.
[image]
Also if your taskbar is on autohide and you receive notification (of any type) from another software your dialog may be under the taskbar. ( you can tell if you have an icon highlighted yellow).
[image: attrib2]
If not on autohide the boxes should always be on the screen and the show windows stacked (or even one of the other choices for re-arranging your windows) should work.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize that the answer was referring to the Windows task bar and not an ArcMap task bar. Once I clicked on "show windows stacked" I saw the attribute table lurking at the very bottom of the screen, behind the task bar. I had to then unlock the task bar and move the table back to the centre of the screen.